# Check via Shell-script if server currently streams via dlna

Tags: networking, shell-script, streaming, dlna

Currently I'm running **uShare** to stream videos from my home-server via DLNA to the TV. On the server there is also running a bash-script which checks if a user is connected via ssh or Samba. If this is not the case, then the server goes to *hibernation-mode*.

Is there any possibility to check via bash-script if the server currently streams a video to my TV? If so, I would like to see a little code example which I could include in my script which check the ssh or Samba connection.

Comment: I would dump the outgoing traffic from your server and sift through it for packets indicating DLNA activity. I'm not really aware of the DLNA protocol, though, so I can't help with actual code.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I'm also not very aware with it. My hope was that it can be solved by the use of grep on the process-list or something like that. Because then it would be easy to add this to the script I mentioned above.

Comment: @Chrispie well, dump `ps xa` when its not streaming v. when it is, and see if they differ... Maybe `lsof` as well, that's another way you might find it (if it has a network socket open).